# views... two random nodes to vote on

Tags: views, 6

I'm trying to use views to show two random nodes for voting on.  I would use something like: filter: Node:terms(with depth), fields:Node body/ title, Sort criteria:GLOBAL:random.  Now, how can I render two random nodes for voting?  Would I have to render them on a custom page-"newpage".tpl.php?  I'm thinking if I used a custom template I would make two 50% regions, have them float left/right, have one height:150px region footer for the voting(below the nodes), then maybe use "popups" so it looks cleaner?  Any ideas on this?  For starters, I'm not sure how I would generate "2" random nodes and have them render in the appropriate "left/right region".  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create them as blocks and place them on a static page together in any region you wish. (Keep it simple)

Comment: Could I render both nodes from the same view though?  If I rewrite the output link on one node, how would it call itself and another node?  Cause, the output link is relative to only one node field.  Also, if I called the voting poll, how could it act relative to the two random nodes being displayed?

Comment: If ur using the voting api and associated voting widget, it should be exposed to views, allowing you to have both voting buttons. Or you could also use views attach.